# nodejs change multiple instances of string between 2 strings

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using this function to change the the string between 2 strings.
but the problem is if there are multiple instances.

```
str = "
    [[101}]changeme1.1{[101]]
    [[102}]changeme2{[102]]
    [[101}]changeme1.2{[101]]
    ";

replaceme2(str, 101,"done1");

function replaceme2(str, num,replacement){
    var startLabel = '[['+num+'}]';


    return str.substring(0, str.indexOf(startLabel))+
    startLabel+
    replacement+
    str.substring(str.indexOf('[{'+num+']]'), str.length);

}

Current Output:
[[101}]done1{[101]]
[[102}]changeme2{[102]]
[[101}]changeme1.2{[101]]

Expected Output:
[[101}]done1{[101]]
[[102}]changeme2{[102]]
[[101}]done1{[101]]
```

Comment: you only do one replacement in your code, you'll need to loop until there's no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use reg:

```js
let str1 = `
    [[101}]changeme1.1[{101]]
    [[102}]changeme2{[102]]
    [[101}]changeme1.2[{101]]
    `;

let str2=`
<html>
    [[101}]<a href="link.php">MY TEXT <span>MY SPAN INSIDE A WITH TEXT</span></a>[{101]] [[102}]
    <a href="link.php">MY TEXTSSSS</a>[{102]] [[101}]
    <a href="link.php">MY TEXT <span>MY SPAN INSIDE A WITH TEXT</span></a>[{101]] [[101}]
    <a href="link.php">MY TEXT <span>MY SPAN INSIDE A WITH TEXT</span></a>[{101]]

</body>
</html>
    `

console.log(replaceme2(str1, 101,"done1"));
console.log(replaceme2(str2, 101,'<a href="done1.php">MY TEXT <span>MY SPAN INSIDE A WITH TEXT</span></a>'));

function replaceme2(str, num, replacement) {

    reg = new RegExp('\\[\\[' + num + '\\}\\]\([\\s\\S]*?\)\\[\\{' + num + '\\]\\]', 'g');
    return result = str.replace(reg, '\[\[' + num + '\}\]' + replacement + '\{\[' + num + '\]\]');
}
```

Comment: somehow works with the sample, but when I use html as the str, it doesnt change.

Comment: <html>
<head></head>
<body>

    [[101}]<a href="link.php">MY TEXT <span>MY SPAN INSIDE A WITH TEXT</span></a>[{101]] [[102}]
    <a href="link.php">MY TEXTSSSS</a>[{102]] [[101}]
    <a href="link.php">MY TEXT <span>MY SPAN INSIDE A WITH TEXT</span></a>[{101]] [[101}]
    <a href="link.php">MY TEXT <span>MY SPAN INSIDE A WITH TEXT</span></a>[{101]]

</body>
</html>

Comment: @Boy expected output?

Comment: basically any, replacing all the [[101}]<a href="link.php">MY TEXT <span>MY SPAN INSIDE A WITH TEXT</span></a>[{101]] to [[101}]ANY[{101]]

Comment: better show a demo so i can know what are you facing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164719/discussion-between-xianshenglu-and-boy).

Comment: Yes, sent you a demo link there

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) only returns the first instance of the string you're searching for.

It's not clear exactly what you're trying to achieve here, but what I would suggest is either:

- If you can split that initial string into an array of strings, do that, and do what you're current doing for each item in the array.
- Create a while loop and keep iterating while it can find more instances to replace.

eg.

```
let startIndex = 0; 
let endIndex = 0; 

while (startIndex > -1 && endIndex > -1) {
   startIndex = str.indexOf(startLabel, startIndex)
   endIndex = str.indexOf('[{'+num+']]', endIndex) 
}
```

(I haven't tested this. There might be an out by one error. )

Or, you know, just use [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned before `indexOf` return only the first occurrence of the index not all the indexes, you'll need to loop over it.

https://repl.it/@OmarQaddoumi/LonelySuperbCivet

Comment: but somehow its clearing the spaces on the other parts, I am using an html as parameter

Comment: also adding [[ to the very first

Comment: if you are trying to parse html I would recommend using an AST instead of doing it by yourself, checkout https://astexplorer.net/, from the top you can select html and eventually you'll get an json object that you can manipulate the way you want, after you parse the html to get to what you need you can then implement the tag replacement you want

Comment: Im using cheeriojs, but replacing is a custom logic of mine